# Combine three ffmpeg commands to encode,, text, image and video on a main video in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

My question is, I have successfully coded the FFMPEG commands for a text, an image and and a video in android. Now as there can only be one single string command to execute I need to combine those three in single one. How am I able to achieve this? I have wasted lots of time but couldn't get anything.

For example : There is a main video in background and I have three different view on top of it and I need to make execution.

Thanks.

Comment: Share your three individual commands, in full.

Comment: commandForImage = new String[]{"-y", "-i", String.valueOf(mVideoPath), "-i", picturePath, "-filter_complex", overlayFilter, "-codec:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", String.valueOf(file)};

Comment: commandForText = new String[]{"-i", String.valueOf(mVideoPath), "-vf", "drawtext=fontsize=" + zz + ":fontfile=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf:fontcolor=black:text="
+ tv.getText().toString() + ":x=" + textX + ":y=" + textY, String.valueOf(file)};

Comment: commandForVideo = new String[]{"-y", "-i", String.valueOf(mVideoPath), "-i", videoPath, "-filter_complex", overlayFilter, "-codec:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", String.valueOf(file)};

Comment: @Gyan Please help me out in this. If you can show me any path or way to accomplish this, it would be very helpful. Also, if you don't know then also let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Busy today; will answer tomorrow.